# mouseenter() and mouseleave() jquery not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a navigation bar with a few elements. I want to add an animation so that the elements change color when the mouse enters and leaves the respective elements. The animation doesn't seem to work, though.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-top-fixed">
    <div class  ="container-fluid">
        <ul class = "navbar-left navbar-brand top-buffer">
            <li >
                <text><b>START BOOTSTRAP</b></text>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class = "navbar-right top-buffer">
            <li>
                <text><b>PORTFOLIO</b></text>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <text><b>ABOUT</b></text>
            </li>   
            <li>
                <text><b>CONTACT</b></text>
            </li>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script src="./jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>      
<script>
    $(document).ready (function () {
        $(".navbar text").mouseenter(function () {  
            $(this).css("color","#18bc9c");
        }); 
        $(".navbar text").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).css("color","#ffffff");
        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to have included jQuery UI but not jQuery.

Comment: there is no `<text>` tag. Broswer won't have default css for it. Generally not a good idea to make up your own tags

Comment: On a related note, there is a `:hover` selector in CSS that makes what you want to do much easier: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: @m1xolyd1an you are misinterpreting the selector which is looking for `text element within class navbar

Comment: @j08691 - Thanks for pointing out! its there in the original code, might have missed out while pasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are missing a closing `});` at the end of your js, and second, i dont see that you have loaded jquery, only jquery-ui, i've set up a fiddle for you with your code working:

http://jsfiddle.net/2q86jn7f/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".navbar text").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#18bc9c");
    });

    $(".navbar text").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
    });
});
```

Comment: its there in the original code, might have missed it during pasting. I will edit  it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close all of the functions. Add one more `});` to the end.

Comment: my bad. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You miss `</ul>` in markup and `});` in `JS` section. but you don't need to `jQuery` for that effect, just use `CSS`, like below:

```
li:hover {
    color: #18bc9c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are missing the jQuery library.
2. Use `span` instead of `text` element. See image below for the reason.
3. Missing the HTML closing tag `ul` and script closing brackets.

**Validation error:**

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".navbar span").mouseenter(function() {

      $(this).css("color", "#18bc9c");

    }),

    $(".navbar span").mouseleave(function() {

      $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");


    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top-fixed">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="navbar-left navbar-brand top-buffer">
      <li>
        <span><b>START BOOTSTRAP</b>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-right top-buffer">
      <li>
        <span><b>PORTFOLIO</b>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><b>ABOUT</b>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><b>CONTACT</b>
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why should he use span instead of text? what is the point with that?

Comment: @taxicala Updated the reason

Comment: I see, i'ts only to make it a valid W3C markup. But it's not the root cause of his issue.

Comment: Yes, it is not. I posted it since the OP is a newbie, I forgot to add the reason before.

Answer (score 0):

`<text>` isn't a valid HTML tag. Ditch it and try `".navbar li"`. Also you didn't close `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code sample, looks like the jQuery library is missing.